# Can I exclude system monitor itself from the CPU usage shown?

Tags: settings, system-monitor

Is it possible, as an option, to ignore the gnome-system-monitor process itself from the gnome-system-monitor calculation (% cpu, etc.) ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible, as an option, to ignore the gnome-system-monitor process itself from the `gnome-system-monitor` calculation:

No. That would make all the figures inaccurate, wouldn't it? e.g. if `gnome-system-monitor` was consuming 2% of CPU, so you only had 98% available, but excluding it showed that you had 100% available?

Try the Processes tab sorted by CPU usage.

Comment: that would tell him how much relative performance each of the running processes needs

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking at the processes tab, just open up a terminal and run `top`.  It will still appear in the list of processes but uses far fewer CPU cycles than the greedy `gnome-system-monitor` does.